# Отслеживание времени ответа с сервера. jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Подскажите как в jQuery можно реализовать следующий механизм.

Мне нужно показывать определенную картинку в момент с отправки запроса($getJSON()) на сервер до момента ответа с него. Как мне поймать этот промежуток времени и назначить для него выполнение такой операции? 
Сразу скажу, что такое можно сделать и проще - без отслеживания статуса запроса(как в xhr). Но хочется разобраться в таких моментах.
Интересует реализация такого механизма для метода $getJson, а если невозможно для него такое сделать - то любого другого.

На чистом js я бы создал объект **XMLHttpRequest**, присвоил бы свойству этого объекта **onreadystatechange** функцию-обработчик, где, проверяя на соответствие значение этого свойства, делал бы необходимую операцию. Но тот я тоже не до конца понимаю: как часто при запросе браузер? отслеживает статус этого объекта?

Спасибо.

Comment: Можно использовать $.ajax(), показывать через beforeSend и скрывать на complete

Comment: @InDevX, отлично, спасибо.